# How do I change fonts dynamically in Angular?

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I'm currently building an app that supports multiple languages using Angular 8 and @ngx-translate (version: 11.0.1).

The app supports a total of 25 languages (for now) but some of them look weird in the font that I'm using (lato). I want to choose the font based on the selected language.

This is how I select the language:

```
@Injectable()
export class LanguageService {

 constructor(private translateService: TranslateService) {
  }

public setLanguage(language: string): boolean {
    if (language && this.isSupportedLanguage(language)) {
      this.translateService.use(language);
      return true;

}
```

Does anyone know if I'm able to add something like setFont() based on the selected language? Thanks.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_lang.asp

Answer (score -1):

u can do it with adding class to body element and css like `body.it { font-family: ***; }`